# moving search box to the right side ( blogger )

Tags: css, search-box

hi I want to know how to make my search bar to the right not in center

the search bar full code below and thank you

www.codepen.io/anon/pen/zKakyJ

www.gamesparadis.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not just add

```
#hbz-searchbox {
 float:right;
}
```